# How to get an access token with the right permissions for a test User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For test purpose of my REST API project I need to get test access tokens of the test user created in my app dashboard on FB.

My application request the user email as a permission.

I check that the users created has the app already installed. Yet when I click on 'get access token' button for those test users, I can only get an access_token with basic infos, email is not available.

Is there a way to get an access token with the right permissions for the test users created in my app dashboard ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is not possible in the app dashboard. The solution is to use the Graph API directly to create Test Users, as descibed at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/accounts/test-users#publish

I was able to use

```
POST /{app-id}/accounts/test-users
```

with an App Access Token and the fields in the request body for `permissions`and `installed`. For the `permissions` you can use commas to separate the list of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the [FB App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) you can create new users with any desired permissions: In the specific App Dashboard go to Roles->Test Users and click on the 'Add' button which brings up a window: 'Create Test Users' from there enable 'Authorize Test Users for This App?' which then reveals a 'Login Permissions' entry field where you can supply any needed permissions.

Also if you want to check the permissions of existing test user's Access Token (which may be obtained under the 'edit' button menu in Roles->Test Users) and then copy and paste it into the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/).

One can also do this using Facebook's Graph API to create users with non-default permissions - this is possible using using their [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

Answer (score -1):

Set "`Authorize Test Users for This App?`" to 'No' when you create a test account. Then log in to your test user (you can do that with the little business card icon) and visit that page where you normally log in to your app. (So authenticate as a normal person) Maybe it isn't the best way, but it worked for me.

*If you don't want to log out from your personal account then click to the pencil icon, and set a password to your test user.*