# Facebook get access_token by username/password

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I implement some facebook related stuff and accessing graph api for that pourposes. But for implement Integration testing I need a simple strategy to get `access_token`. So I create test user for that. How could I get `access_token` only with server side involved, without including browser in the chain. Ideally I just need to exchange login/password to the token.

---

**Correct workflow loooks like this:**

According the correct answer, there is special tests users provided by facebook.
To to be able to tests system properly you need to do the following flow

1. Get application access token
2. Request application's tests user's via `"GET /{app_id}/accounts/test-users"`
3. Parse response and extract access_tokens for each user from that response.

Comment: 2. should be a `POST` instead of a `GET`

Comment: No, I don't need to create it, I need to read a list of existed users, so that's why GET there

Comment: OK, but this means then that you have to create the Test User in the App Dashboard first. And the Access Token of existing Test Users can also be derived from the App Dashboard.

Comment: Yes, actually I already have them. I use testusers for testing, but don't know how to get access_token for them. And that's why you help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exchange the login/password for an Access Token, but you can create test users programmatically. Have a look here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/test-user
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/accounts/test-users
- [How to get an access token with the right permissions for a test User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695643/how-to-get-an-access-token-with-the-right-permissions-for-a-test-user/24697707#24697707)
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/permissions/

Comment: Ok, that seems good. But can I get test user's access token somehow simply, if I have an application credential?

Comment: If you create the test user programmatically via `POST /{app-id}/accounts/test-users`, you get the `id` and the `access_token` in the response

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can´t.

Server side you can only get an App Access Token, Page Access Token or extend an existing Access Token.

So it depends on what you need to achieve, if you just want to get public stuff from a Facebook Page, even an App Access Token may be good enough. But you cannot create User Access Tokens server side.

It may be possible with real test users created via the Graph API itself though, see Tobis answer for links about that. But it is definitely not possible with username/password.